# When did LOC adopt modified Hepburn?

Tags: translation, history, culture, rōmaji

If I look in Google Ngrams, I see that the transliteration "honbu", meaning HQ, basically didn't exist until 1964.  But it didn't surpass "hombu" until 1976.  I believe Modified Hepburn was introduced in the 1950s, but I am wondering when the Library of Congress adopted it as an ALA standard--in maybe the early 1970s?  I can't find any dates for this information, though I have looked on the LOC website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about romanisation instead of being about the Japanese language. It's also not really about romanisation, but about the history of the change.

Comment: I think questions about writing Japanese down should be considered on-topic.

Comment: I have forwarded your question to a librarian at the LOC. If I receive an answer, I will gladly post it here :-)

Answer (score 4):

1983.

In the deepest corners of the Library of Congress website, you can find the [Spring 1983 issue of the Cataloging Service Bulletin](https://www.loc.gov/aba/publications/FreeCSB/CSB_020.pdf). On page 51, you can see the specification calling for the modified Hepburn system for romanization.

An excerpt of the paragraph:

> The modified Hepburn system of romanization as employed in **Kenkyusha's
>   New Japanese-English Dictionary** (3rd and later editions) is used.
>   For the syllabic nasal, "n" is always used preceding "b," "m," and "p."
>   Romanization for words of foreign origin follows the American National
>   Standard system for the romanization of Japanese, e.g., ベトナム
>   Betonamu; ヴェトナム Vetonamu.